# Are there any deities or mythological beasts inspired by snow leopards?

Tags: mythical-creatures, myth-identification, animals

I don't know a lot about the mythology of central Asian cultures (where the snow leopard comes from). I'm trying to find more information on the cultural impact the animal could have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a collection of snow leopard myths on the [Snow Leopard Conservancy](http://snowleopardconservancy.org/) website:

- [Nepalese Myths Surrounding Snow Leopards (1)](http://snowleopardconservancy.org/text/myth/nepmyths.htm)
- [Nepalese Myths Surrounding Snow Leopards (2)](http://snowleopardconservancy.org/text/myth/nepmythstoo.htm)
- [Tibetan Myths Surrounding Snow Leopards](http://snowleopardconservancy.org/text/myth/tibmyths.htm)
- [Snow Leopards, Mountain Spirits and Sacred Space in Northern Pakistan](http://snowleopardconservancy.org/text/myth/pakmyths.htm)
- [The Otter and the Snow Leopard](http://snowleopardconservancy.org/text/myth/pakmyths2.htm)
- [The Four Harmonious Brothers](http://snowleopardconservancy.org/text/myth/ladakhmyths.htm)
- [Snow Leopard, Otter, and Domestic Cat](http://snowleopardconservancy.org/text/myth/zanskmyths.htm)